# Can't create a loop to fetch all the titles from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, pyppeteer

I've written a script in ***`python`*** in combination with ***`pyppeteer`*** to scrape the ***`titles`*** and ***`links`*** to the titles of different posts from a webpage. The thing is when I run my script, it can parse the first `title` and the `link` of the first post there. My intention is to create a loop to get them all. As I'm very new to work using this library, I can't find any idea how can I create a loop. Any help will be appreciated.

My script so far:

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

async def get_titles_n_links():
    wb = await launch(headless=True)
    page = await wb.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping')

    element = await page.querySelector('.question-hyperlink')
    title = await page.evaluate('(element) => element.textContent', element)
    link = await page.evaluate('(element) => element.href', element)
    print(f'{title}\n{link}\n')
    await wb.close()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(get_titles_n_links())
```

Comment: Try to use [querySelectorAll](https://miyakogi.github.io/pyppeteer/reference.html?highlight=queryselector#pyppeteer.page.Page.querySelectorAll) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will be like:

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

async def get_titles_n_links():
    wb = await launch(headless=True)
    page = await wb.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping')

    elements = await page.querySelectorAll('.question-hyperlink')

    for element in elements:
        title = await page.evaluate('(element) => element.textContent', element)
        link = await page.evaluate('(element) => element.href', element)
        print(f'{title}\n{link}\n')

    await wb.close()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(get_titles_n_links())
```

Comment: That's more like it. Thanks @Nick for the solution.